# Using an XSL variable as Xpath value in xsl:apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to use the content of a node as an Xpath reference. Unfortunately I have not found the way to achieve this so far.

So here is a little example of the type of XML I am trying to process:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b name="1">
      <e>value1</e>
    </b>
    <b name="2">
      <e>value2</e>
    </b>
  </a>
  <c>
    <d name="3">
      <ref>/root/a/b[@name = "1"]</ref>
    </d>
    <d name="4">
      <ref>/root/a/b[@name = "2"]</ref>
    </d>
  </c>
</root>
```

In there the `<ref>` nodes contain  Xpath to some in-file nodes containing the required value.

Here is the type of XSL file I was trying to put together to process this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/c/d"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d">
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="ref/text()"/>
    for node <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$var1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
   value = <xsl:value-of select="e"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I process the above XML file with the proposed XSL I am getting the following result:

```
for node 3/root/a/b[@name = "1"]
for node 4/root/a/b[@name = "2"]
```

Obviously the content of $var1 is not evaluated as a valid xpath.

Note: if I replace $var1 with /root/a/b[@name = "1"] I am getting

```
    for node 3
   value = value1
    for node 4
   value = value1
```

Which is closer to what I want but the node 4 is obviously no pointing to the value2 node anymore.

What am I missing?

Is this possible with XSL?

Is there some problem with "dyanmic evaluation" and should I use some other mean (like xsl:function or xsl:call-template)?

Thanks for you help.

---

### **Solution:**

As suggested by "Daniel Haley" using dyn:evaluate does solve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                            xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
                            version="1.0"
                            extension-element-prefixes="dyn">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/c/d"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d"><xsl:variable name="var1" select="ref/text()"/>
    for node <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dyn:evaluate($var1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
   value = <xsl:value-of select="e"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using for example xsltproc with this XSL stylesheet does produce the expected result.

```
$ xsltproc ./file.xsl ./file.xml 

    for node 3
   value = value1
    for node 4
   value = value2
$
```

I have not investigated the xsl:evaluate method yet.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`xsl:evaluate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) in XSLT 3.0 (provided your processor supports it).

You can also the use [`dyn:evaluate`](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/) EXSLT extension function (again, provided your processor supports it).

Comment: And another solution, if neither of those work for you, is to dynamically generate an XSLT stylesheet and then execute that stylesheet.

Comment: So, this seems to mean that what I am trying to achieve is not doable with plain XSLT 1.0.  
  
The XML editor  I am using (XmlCopyEditor) does not seem to support XSLT 3.0 or EXSLT. Too bad ...  
  
I am going to investigate to find a stand alone XSLT processor that would support one of these.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  
I edited my question to add the solution based on the dyn:evaluate EXSLT extension suggested by Daniel Haley.