# How to use variable as value in xsl:apply-templates?

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I'm trying to extract some data from xml file and pass it to many html files based on specific nodes.
My `source.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <feature>Product description escaped html tags</feature>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <feature>Product description escaped html tags</feature>
    </product>
.........................
    <product>
        <id>5</id>
        <feature>Product description escaped html tags</feature>
    </product>
</products>
```

Expected result: to have multiple html files with content like this:

```
<p>1</p>
Product description with html tags
```

I'm using this python code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

doc = ET.parse('source.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('modify.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)

products = doc.findall('product')

for product in products:
    i = product.find('id')
    n = ET.XSLT.strparam(str(i))
    describ = transform(doc, item_num=n)
    f = open('file_nr_{}.html'.format(i.text), 'wb')
    f.write(describ)
    f.close()
```

My current stylesheet `modify.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:param name="item_num"/>

    <xsl:template match="/products">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="product[id=$item_num]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id" >
        <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::feature" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

..gives me multiple complete empty zero bytes files. But when i change line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="product[id=$item_num]" />
```

to this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="product[id&lt;4]" />
```

it gives me five files with the same content:

```
<p>1</p>Product description with still escaped html tags
Product description with still escaped html tags

<p>2</p>Product description with still escaped html tags
Product description with still escaped html tags

<p>3</p>Product description with still escaped html tags
Product description with still escaped html tags
```

I don't know how to:

- properly use variable in path matching only one `<product>` with specific `<id>`
- effective disable escaping
- properly ask google to find solution... ;)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165765/how-to-split-an-xml-file-into-several-other-files-properly-once-a-certain-tag) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332147/using-an-xsl-variable-as-xpath-value-in-xslapply-templates) and [this](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/09/xslt-variables-in-attribute-match-predicates.html) and [this](https://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/xsl/frames.html) and searched [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) but I cannot use this knowledge in my case. Probably because I still don't understand how passing a variable value works. I'm trying to deal with this on my own since friday, but the only result I have is a headache.. Please help.

Comment: Unrelated note: Use a context manager, i.e. `with open(f'file_nr_{i}.html', 'wb'):` instead of an unguarded `open()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product[id=$item_num]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id" >
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::feature" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

applies templates to `<product>` nodes, but has a template for `<id>` nodes.

Make a template for `<product>` nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="id"/></p>
    <xsl:value-of select="feature" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

Whenever XSLT cannot find a template for a specific node, it falls back to default behavior. Default behavior is "copy child text nodes to output, and apply templates to child elements". This explains why you see what you see with your code.

---

Regarding your other issue: `.find('...')` returns *XML nodes*, not string values, i.e. `.find('id')` finds an `<id>` element. You wanted to pass the `.text` of the found node as the XSLT parameter, not the node itself:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

doc = ET.parse('source.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('modify.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)

products = doc.findall('product')

for product in products:
    i = product.find('id').text
    describ = transform(doc, item_num=i)
    with open(f'file_nr_{i}.html', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(describ)
```

Comment: Thank you, what you mentioned is my obvious mistake. Your answer is getting me closer to my goal: now when using 
`<xsl:apply-templates select="product[id&lt;4]" />`
I have five html files with data from three first `<product>`  in nicely looking html. 
But still while using variable:
`<xsl:apply-templates select="product[id=$item_num]" />`
I have five empty files.
I think it is something about the way I'm using it. Or maybe about versions of software?

Comment: @JWPB When you add `<xsl:value-of select="$item_num" />` to your main template, what does it print? (My suspicion is that the value of `$item_num` is not really equal to any of your `<id>` elements.)

Comment: Of course you are right! Variable in main tamplate prints elements: `<Element id at 0x1c5edcbb8c0>` and so on. Thank you so much! I knew that there was something with the way I used variable. I followed with [this working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165765/how-to-split-an-xml-file-into-several-other-files-properly-once-a-certain-tag) and thought it will be almost the same. Can you explain me the difference, please. It's great to have a working code, but I'd love to know, why it's working. :)

Comment: @JWPB In the other example `i` is an `int` (it comes from a `range()` call). In your code `i` is an Element object. Converting an `int` to string will not give you any surprises. Converting an Element object to string gives you `"<Element id at 0x1c5edcbb8c0>"`.

Comment: Understand, thank you! When I applied your advice to my "sample xml file" (shown here) everything is working like a charm including character escaping. Now I have to find, why while processing my "original xml file" it does not escape special characters in `<feature>` elements. This text is original in CDATA. Could it be the reason? Or is this out of scope of this thread?

Comment: @JWPB No, CDATA is not the reason. What "special characters" do you mean?

Comment: E.g `<![CDATA[&lt;div  data-index=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;]]>` in source xml file and `&lt;div  data-index=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;` in output html file.

Comment: @JWPB Oh, in this case the your input data is broken. It's double-escaped (one level of escaping through `&gt;` and so on, and another level of escaping through `<![CDATA`. `disable-output-escaping` only removes one level of escaping. Fix your input data, if you can.

Comment: So that's the point! Tank you once again. Now I know what to do.

Comment: @JWPB For example an XML element containing `<![CDATA[<div  data-index="1"></div>]]>` is fine, or `&lt;div  data-index=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`, but not the combination.